# Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis is FDA complaint?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

Am working for a Medical devices company and we are trying to use Static code analysis tools for our development.Can somebody help us in validating whether Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis feature is complaint to FDA or not?

Comment: Is [this the FDA document in question](http://www.fda.gov/medicaldevices/deviceregulationandguidance/guidancedocuments/ucm085281.htm)? If yes, then static analysis tools are only a small (but important) part of ensuring compliance, but they don't specify which tools you should use, as far as I can tell. (VS 2012 Code Analysis is a static code analysis tool)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.So you mean to say that i can directly use VS2012 code Analysis as my static code analysis tool with out any other tool(VS2012 CA) validations?

Comment: I guess it's enough, but I can't say for sure. [This msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134108(v=vs.100).aspx) is for VS2010, but you might find it helpful.

Comment: So after doing some research we found that there are few paid tools which are already complaint to FDA like Klockwork,Coverity,Para soft dotTest..etc.But our management has finalized to use VS2010 CA feature after doing the validation by out Tools validation team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe TFS *can be validated* for FDA Compliance for Static Code Analysis and other requirements depending on your QSIA Intended Use. As mentioned in OP's comment the key is validating how you are using a tool, not whether it is validated "out of the box". I believe you must validate that you have configured and use static code analysis in a way that is compliant. Just having a tool doesn't make its output automatically compliant (unless there is a "FDA-compliant" setting that cannot be disabled :-)).

[Food and Drug Administration (FDA) Compliance with Visual Studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134108(v=vs.100).aspx) (MSDN whitepaper by Northwest Cadence, June 2011)
has an extensive walkthrough of TFS features mapped to FDA compliance and FDA document "General Principles of Software Validation". Static code analysis is specifically mentioned. Here is the relevant excerpt:

> Static Code Analysis
>   The static code analysis in Visual Studio 2010 has several hundred rules that check code for potential code errors in several areas, which include design, naming, reliability and security. These rules can be combined into rule sets that allow only a specific subset of the rules to be run, highlighting potential problems. These range from the “Minimum Recommended Rules," which focus on the most critical problems in your code, including potential security holes, application crashes, and other important logic and design errors, to the “All Rules” set. which contains every available rule. It’s very easy to configure a custom rule set to focus your code analysis specifically toward your needs.

There may be other references that are (or will be) relevant. Try following search keywords:  TFS FDA (or better yet use [+TFS +FDA](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%2BTFS%20%2BFDA) to force major search engines to have both terms).  [+VS +FDA](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%2BVS%20%2BFDA) might return other relevant results especially if you are looking specifically for code analysis rather than overall compliance for eSignature and other Part 11 requirements.

Please vote if you found this helpful. Thanks! -Zephan

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 is not compliant to FDA

Comment: Please be more specific. What specific parts of VS2012 are not FDA Compliant? Were there specific customizations/configurations required that your company/team was unable to implement?

Out of the box VS2012 is not validated for full FDA Part 11 compliance. However VS is just the front-end. However I believe it can be validated for FDA compliance requirements depending on your specified "Intended Use". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134108(v=vs.100).aspx#bkmk_coding specifically mentions static code analysis. Hope this helps.